# Making a new migration for a Django app, ignoring all other app models

Tags: django, django-migrations

I have made model changes to a Django model `Bicycle` in app `bicycles` in a project where another unrelated app `cars` has a model `Car` which has changes that has model changes without the accompanying makemigrations. The developer of `cars.Car` is unavailable and I cannot change their source code, but I still need to make a new migration for `bicycles.Bicycle`.

Is this possible at all in Django 2.2? When I run `makemigrations bicycles`, I get this:

> You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'year' to car without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows).
>   Please select a fix:
>   1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
>   2) Quit, and let me add a default in models.py
>   Select an option:

As I said, the `bicycles` app is completely unrelated to `cars`, so I feel like I should be able to make the migration for the `bicycles` app *only*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by renaming `cars/migrations/__init__.py` to something else, that way Django was unable to find it and I could make my `bicycles` migration as expected.